# Can I delete default files in public HTML folder?

Tags: hosting

First time uploading files to make my website online. In the public HTML folder there is a folder with my domain name. I assume that I should upload my website files in that folder. But there are some files and folders already available there, can I delete all of them?

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MlPqs.png) are the file names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your public html folder should be a clean slate, and shouldn't have anything inside of it if this is your first time uploading files to a new domain. That being said, as other answers have stated, if you purchased the domain from someone else, I would make a backup of their files and send them to them before doing anything.

Those files you linked are a website, so I would preview the Index.html file and see what it's actually hosting, could be nothing, could be something important. You never know until you check it out. Make a back up, and if it's nothing you need, delete everything and start fresh.

Comment: I deleted all files and uploaded my website files, but I got 403 error :(

Comment: The most common reason for this error is that directory browsing is forbidden for the Web site. Most Web sites want you to navigate using the URLs in the Web pages for that site. They do not often allow you to browse the file directory structure of the site. For example try the following URL (then hit the 'Back' button in your browser to return to this page):

http://www.checkupdown.com/accounts/grpb/B1394343/

This URL should fail with a 403 error saying "Forbidden: You don not have permission to access /accounts/grpb/B1394343/ on this server".

Comment: @AnnieAlan Glad I could be of some help. However please, mark as this as solved so we can move along and so that this does not show up in the unanswered queue.

Answer (score 0):

If the website is brand new `yes` i would delete them and upload your entire new website to the server - this should be absolutely fine - if someone use to own the domain or you brought the domain some provider put pre-defined files in there just so a web page shows with content in.

TAKE A BACKUP BEFORE HAND JUST IN CASE :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can , there is probably nothing there you will need :)

Comment: I think the question required a "YES" or "NO" answer, and there is no need to put the answer as a comment since it had the solution to the problem.